# Sending python requests and handling JSON lists

Tags: python, json, list

I am sending requests to a crypto network for data on accounts. You get sent back information, but I haven't yet encountered lists being sent in JSON until now. I want to parse certain information, but am having trouble because the JSON is a list and is not as easy to parse compared to normal JSON data.

```
import requests
import json
url = ' https://s1.ripple.com:51234/'
payload = {
    "method": "account_objects",
    "params": [
        {
            "account": "r9cZA1mLK5R5Am25ArfXFmqgNwjZgnfk59",
            "ledger_index": "validated",
            "type": "state",
            "deletion_blockers_only": False,
            "limit": 10
        }
    ]
}
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
print(response.text)
data = response.text
parsed = json.loads(data)
price = parsed['result']
price = price['account_objects']
for Balance in price:
    print(Balance)
```

You will receive all the tokens the account holds and the value. I can not figure out how to parse this correctly and receive the correct one. This particular test account has a lot of tokens so I will only show the first tokens info.

**RESULT**

{'Balance': {'currency': 'ASP', 'issuer': 'rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrBZbvji', 'value': '0'}, 'Flags': 65536, 'HighLimit': {'currency': 'ASP', 'issuer': 'r9cZA1mLK5R5Am25ArfXFmqgNwjZgnfk59', 'value': '0'}, 'HighNode': '0', 'LedgerEntryType': 'RippleState', 'LowLimit': {'currency': 'ASP', 'issuer': 'r3vi7mWxru9rJCxETCyA1CHvzL96eZWx5z', 'value': '10'}, 'LowNode': '0', 'PreviousTxnID': 'BF7555B0F018E3C5E2A3FF9437A1A5092F32903BE246202F988181B9CED0D862', 'PreviousTxnLgrSeq': 1438879, 'index': '2243B0B630EA6F7330B654EFA53E27A7609D9484E535AB11B7F946DF3D247CE9'}

I want to get the first bit of info, here. `{'Balance': {'currency': 'ASP', 'issuer': 'rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrBZbvji', 'value': '0'}`,
Specifically 'value' and the number

I have tried to take parse 'Balance' but since it is a list it is not as straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up lists and dictionaries. In order to access a dictionary by key, you need to invoke the key, as such:

```py
    for Balance in price:
        print(Balance['Balance'])
```

Yields the following results:

```
{'currency': 'CHF', 'issuer': 'rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrBZbvji', 'value': '-0.3488146605801446'}
{'currency': 'BTC', 'issuer': 'rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrBZbvji', 'value': '0'}
{'currency': 'USD', 'issuer': 'rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrBZbvji', 'value': '-11.68225001668339'}
```

If you only wanted to extract the value, you simply dive one level deeper:

```
    for Balance in price:
        print(Balance['Balance']['value')
```

Which yields:

```
-0.3488146605801446
0
-11.68225001668339
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfectly. Thanks for the explanation as well, I need to reread lists and dictionaries to understand them better. This was a big help, I was stuck on this for a while.

Comment: Happy to have helped! If this helped solve your problem, please mark this answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

I assume that under `price['account_objects']` you have a list of dictionaries? And then in each dictionary you have in one of the keys: `'Balance': {'currency': 'ASP', 'issuer': 'rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrBZbvji', 'value': '0'`. If so, why don't you iterate over the list and then access each dictionary, like:

```py
account_objects = price['account_objects']
for account_object in price:
    print(account_object['Balance'])
```